# User ID problem when programmatically creating nodes

Tags: nodes, migrations

I have written a migration script that migrates data from Drupal 4.7 to Drupal 6. It is highly customized for my purposes. I am able to create new nodes with no problem. However, after I save the nodes I am noticing that the user that created it is showing up as "Anonymous" and in the database it has a uid of 0. Yet, when I wrote my code I have set it to 1 when the migrated user id has not been found. I have even double-checked to make sure that it is setting the uid to 1.

Why would this be setting it to uid = 0 when I specifically set it to 1?

```
  $node = new stdClass();
  $node->type = 'opinion_article';
  $node->title = $blog->title;
  $node->body = $blog->body;
  $node->teaser = $blog->teaser;

  //We need to associate the content to the user that created it.
  $node->uid = 1;
  $node->name = $account->name;
  $node->status = $blog->status;
  $node->comment = $blog->comment;
  $node->promote = $blog->promote;

  //Set a default topic of Migration Data.
  $node->field_topics[] = array('nid' => 820); ###### Remember to update this node ID to reflect the topic nid on dev once created. It is nid 916 on the dev server.  ################

  //Set the parent group
  $node->og_parent = $parent_nid;

  //Create the node
  $node = node_submit($node);
  node_save($node);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that [node_submit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_submit/6) contains the following code.

```
  if (user_access('administer nodes')) {
    // Populate the "authored by" field.
    if ($account = user_load(array('name' => $node->name))) {
      $node->uid = $account->uid;
    }
    else {
      $node->uid = 0;
    }
  }
```

When it's not able to load the user object having `$node->name` as username, it sets the user ID to zero.
As you have already set the values for the node object, it is useless to pass the node to `node_submit()`; it would be better to just pass it to `node_save()`.